# Generating a XML by designing a stylesheet based out of certain conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

this is what I'm trying to do and finding it difficult to proceed on this since I am new to coding in general, I started looking at few examples and was able to understand how to use value-of and sort order="ascending" but I don't think it can be applied in xsl template(I may be wrong) hence I removed all of it and just was able to progress until the .xsl file attached below .Based on certain conditions I am willing to accomplish the below output.
The conditions are as follows:

1. Get all the landscape_names which has theatres in alphabetical order.
2. Get all the landscape_names which has the zip code 60608 in alphabetical order
3. Get all the landscape_names which has a **beach and at least one food court** in alphabetical order
4. Get all the landscape_names which has at least 155 acres, which is sorted with the largest landscape first.
   This is the output file which I am expecting. landscapeoutput.xml
   I am using xsl:1.0

```html
<results>
        <theatres_info>
            <landscape name ="CheeseCake Factory location" acres ="259.3"/>
            <landscape name ="Hospital Property" acres ="223.3"/>
            <landscape name ="IT company" acres ="148.9"/>
            <landscape name ="Private Property" acres ="500.2"/>
        </theatres_info>
        <zip_data_60608> 
            <landscape name ="CheeseCake Factory location" acres ="259.3"/>    
            <landscape name ="Hospital Property" acres ="223.3"/>    
        </zip_data_60608> 
        <beach_data>
            <landscape name ="CheeseCake Factory location" acres ="259.3"/>    
            <landscape name ="Hospital Property" acres ="223.3"/>  
            <landscape name ="IT company" acres ="148.9"/> 
        </beach_data>
        <landscape_area>
            <landscape name ="Private Property" acres ="500.2"/>
            <landscape name ="CheeseCake Factory location" acres ="259.3"/>    
            <landscape name ="Hospital Property" acres ="223.3"/>  
            <landscape name ="IT company" acres ="148.9"/> 
        </landscape_area>
    </results>
```

This is the xml file from which data is to be retrieved.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<landscapes>
    <landscape>
        <landscape_no>1</landscape_no>
        <landscape_name>CheeseCake Factory location</landscape_name>
        <location>Glendale Avenue</location>
        <zip>60608</zip>
        <acres>259.3</acres>
        <baseball_court>0</baseball_court>
        <beach>2</beach>
        <foodcourt>1</foodcourt>
        <recreationcentre>2</recreationcentre>
        <theatres>1</theatres>
        <shape_area>430341.671424</shape_area>
    </landscape>   
     <landscape>
        <landscape_no>2</landscape_no>
        <landscape_name>Private Property</landscape_name>
        <location>Fullerton st</location>
        <zip>30508</zip>
        <acres>500.2</acres>
        <baseball_court>0</baseball_court>
        <beach>0</beach>
        <recreationcentre>2</recreationcentre>
        <foodcourt>1</foodcourt>
        <theatres>1</theatres>
        <shape_area>430341.671424</shape_area>
    </landscape>   
     <landscape>
        <landscape_no>3</landscape_no>
        <landscape_name>Commerical Property</landscape_name>
        <location>Milwaukee Ave</location>
        <zip>60608</zip>
        <acres>223.3</acres>
        <baseball_court>0</baseball_court>
        <beach>4</beach>
        <foodcourt>2</foodcourt>
        <recreationcentre>2</recreationcentre>
        <theatres>1</theatres>
        <shape_area>67895.4468</shape_area>
    </landscape>   
     <landscape>
        <landscape_no>4</landscape_no>
        <landscape_name>IT company</landscape_name>
        <location>Columbian st</location>
        <zip>60988</zip>
        <acres>148.9</acres>
        <baseball_court>5</baseball_court>
        <beach>0</beach>
        <foodcourt>3</foodcourt>
        <recreationcentre>9</recreationcentre>
        <theatres>1</theatres>
        <shape_area>32342.1232</shape_area>
    </landscape>
</landscapes>
```

This is the xsl file on which I just got started which is not right after several attempts hence posting here ,I am not sure how to proceed on the logic part based on the conditions.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="landscapes/landscape">
            <xsl:value-of select="landscape_name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="acres" />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After trying out not able to do it I'm posting here. Please help me understand with a solution to this, explaining as to how to approach the problem statement which will be really helpful for me to learn.

Comment: I hesitate whether I should answer this. These questions  are rather trivial and you should know the answer after spending an hour with an XSLT tutorial. Your attempt suggests you haven't done that, and it seems like you are really asking for a tutorial rather than help with a specific problem.

Comment: Different people learn in different ways, but learning a programming language purely by looking at examples is not an approach I would recommend. It's very easy to build an incorrect model in your head about how the examples work, and once you've done that, it's very hard to correct it later. I always start by reading a book, to get the concepts and the terminology straight.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could solve one of the problems you have presented:

> 4. Get all the landscape_names which has at least 155 acres, which is sorted with the largest landscape first.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/landscapes">
    <results>
        <landscape_area>
            <xsl:for-each select="landscape[acres >= 155]">
                <xsl:sort select="acres" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <landscape name ="{landscape_name}" acres ="{acres}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </landscape_area>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To understand how this works, you should read up on *predicates* and *attribute value templates*. Then you should be able to apply the same principles to the other problems in your question.

Note that the result when applied to your input example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <landscape_area>
    <landscape name="Private Property" acres="500.2"/>
    <landscape name="CheeseCake Factory location" acres="259.3"/>
    <landscape name="Commerical Property" acres="223.3"/>
  </landscape_area>
</results>
```

is different from the output you show. Your output shows a landscape that is not present in the input and includes a landscape that does not meet the stated condition.